# Kapacitor: Copying a subset to a new measurement

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

I want to copy all non-zero entries to a new measurement. My tick looks like this:

`batch
  |query('select * from "asdf"."autogen"."linedata" where value != 0').every(1d).period(1d)
  |influxDBOut().database('asdf').measurement('newlinedata')`

Unfortunately the tags are not preserved. How can I do that? I want to copy all the tags without specifying them explicitly.

The reason behind this is, that I want to remove all zero values. Therefore the next step would be to remove the original series and then copy the data back. If you have a better solution, please tell me.

Thanks!